# Understanding error_reporting() in PHP

Tags: php

I have this one line to execute

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
```

I got the notice

```
Notice: Undefined index action ....
```

Then I wrote these lines before that

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

`Notice`s disappeared. Then again I commented out above those two lines then *notices did not appeared*

My question is, does `error_reporting` sets the `E_ALL`. and the others, for that particular website or page or for the server?

Comment: Maybe `$_REQUEST['action']` was defined the second time? Anyway, it should be `$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : null;`

Comment: I believe it's for that particular page if you've put it at the top. If you want to change it globally you're better off doing so in your .htaccess file. On another note, the way to get around that notice is to do isset().

Comment: calling `error_reporting` and `ini_set()` in a script affect **ONLY** that script, and only the code that comes after the calls. They do not make the settings you've changed permanent, or affect the rest of the server.

Comment: @MarcB Why is it that I comment those lines and access that page again, notice still does not show....

Answer (score 0):

Error reporting typically sets the reporting level on the page, it can be uses globally across the server by changing the level thorough php.ini

But using it on pages,will affect the page it's on/included with

Comment: Why is it that I comment those lines and access that page again, notice still does not show...

Comment: Try a hard refresh of the page CTRL + F5